# Unable to install vim plugin in raspberry pi(vundle)

Tags: vim, raspbian, vim-plugin, vundle

I am trying to install plugin for python in vim,but i am unable to do that. I removed vi tiny from Raspberry pi and installed vi 8.0 I followed instruction from this site

https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/

I updated my vimrc file from sudo user in folder /home/etc/vim/vimrc

added these lines in vimrc file.

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
" used Bundle instead of Plugin)

" ...

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

whenever I trying to install plugin I get an error E942: Not an editor command: PluginInstall
[E942 error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUdyQ.jpg)

when typing :Scriptname in VIM it show this

[scriptname Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3jIk.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you skipped the installation of vundle

Comment: I installed vundle using this `git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

Comment: Try replacing `gmarik` by `VundleVim`. Github project is VundleVim not gmarik, also `Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim`, see [Github README](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)